# Exchange invites accepted twice - once from mail, once from calendar

Tags: macos, mail.app, calendar, exchange-activesync

When I receive an exchange meeting invite, it appears in my email inbox (with controls to accept/decline) and also in my calendar (under the small invitations icon). When I accept from one, the other remains. To clear them, I have to accept in both applications, and two  replies are sent to the organizer.

How can I avoid this? I would like them to sync, so that when I accept an invite in Mail, it is no longer listed in Calendar.